# Intersect in mongodb from two records

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

MongoDb + Spring boot  + intersectsArrays

I want to fetch randomly 15 users and know there common interest. Document structure  is something like this

```
{
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "593f773202338a47584b351e"
    },
    "interests": [
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "5957933cf3c5f5253ec9476c"
        },
        "name": "abc1",
        "facebookId": "123"
      }]
    ]
  }
```

Need to fetch common interest for each user returned by mongo.

Below is my Spring boot code

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria().andOperator(Criteria.where("lastLoginDate").gte(Utility.getDateBeforeDays(lastLoginNewerThan)));
        Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(new CustomAggregationOperation(maxRecords),
                Aggregation.match(criteria),Aggregation.project("id","name")
                );
        AggregationResults<Users> userResults = operations.aggregate(agg, Users.class, Users.class);
        List<Users> users = userResults.getMappedResults();
```

Comment: Your code doesn't have much detail and can't infer as to which part is not working for you. Your title suggest to get intersection between two arrays but your post suggest to fetch common interest across multiple users. Can you clarify further by adding sample expected output and input to the post ?

Comment: @Veeram its Tinder kind of application where i get randomly 15 guys and need to show number of common interest. I am able to fetch 15 nearby guys using above code but not able to find common interests. Its something like this. I am sachin searching for nearBy Guys and get your profile then i have to show how many common interests are there between us.

Comment: You can use [setIntersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) to compare your interest's ( which should be input )  against each of random guys interest's.

Comment: @veeram Can you please provide code snippet for this in spring boot

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Spring Mongo Data api doesn't provide a way to pass a list of values as input to the set intersection operator.

You can use `AggressionExpression` to provide custom implementation.Include below projection in project stage.

```
.and(new AggregationExpression() {
       @Override
        public DBObject toDbObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {
            return new BasicDBObject("$setIntersection",
                Arrays.<Object> asList(
                     Arrays.<Object> asList("reading","movies"),
                         "$interests"));
            }
}).as("commonInterests"));
```

You can wrap the expression as a lambda for Java 8

```
and(context -> new BasicDBObject("$setIntersection",
            Arrays.<Object> asList(
                 Arrays.<Object> asList("reading","movies"),
                   "$interests")))
.as("commonInterests");
```